# How to match an url with argument type url -django

Tags: django

Example:

```
url('ajax/(?P<url>w+)','views.ajax')
```

Error message:

```
ajax/https://www.youtube.com/watch, didn't match any of these.
```

but this is failing to match.
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer for this question.

I used regular expression to match any thing **[.*]**
Or we can get this by usage of forms in django to get the requires values from the page.

Comment: It would be better if you added example